# How to fix "Empty paragraph passed to '@sa' command" when using GLFW

Tags: c, xcode, glfw, glew

I have been trying to create a basic app in xcode using glfw and glew but i always get the same error: "Empty paragraph passed to '@sa' command".

What does this error mean and how do I fix it?

My code is:

```
    #include <stdio.h>

#include <GL/glew.h>
#include <GLFW/glfw3.h>

int main(void)
{
    GLFWwindow* window;

    // Initialize the library
    if (!glfwInit())
        return -1;

    // Specify the minimum OpenGL version
    glfwWindowHint(GLFW_CONTEXT_VERSION_MAJOR, 3);
    glfwWindowHint(GLFW_CONTEXT_VERSION_MINOR, 2);
    glfwWindowHint(GLFW_OPENGL_PROFILE, GLFW_OPENGL_CORE_PROFILE);
    glfwWindowHint(GLFW_OPENGL_FORWARD_COMPAT, GL_TRUE);

    // Create a windowed mode window and its OpenGL context
    window = glfwCreateWindow(640, 480, "Hello World", NULL, NULL);
    if (!window)
    {
        glfwTerminate();
        return -1;
    }

    // Make the window's context current
    glfwMakeContextCurrent(window);

    printf("GL Version: %s", glGetString(GL_VERSION));

    // Loop until the user closes the window
    while (!glfwWindowShouldClose(window))
    {
        // Render here
        glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

        // Swap front and back buffers
        glfwSwapBuffers(window);

        // Poll for and process events
        glfwPollEvents();
    }

    glfwTerminate();
    return 0;
}
```